How to Structure a Firebase Database and Query Documents from District in Swift?
I am developing an app using SwiftUI and Swift. I have a Firebase database with the following structure:
Collection named products,
Documents representing countries,
Subcollections representing districts,
Documents representing cities,
Subcollections containing various documents.
Given this structure, how can I retrieve all documents from a specific district, noting that a district contains multiple cities, each with its own set of documents?
Any code examples or explanations on how to achieve this in Swift would be greatly appreciated.

Documents go in Storage and the URL for the documents goes in the database


Subcollections representing districts


how can I retrieve all documents from a specific district?

This would require that you can get a list of subcollections under a given path, which is not an operation that Firestore supports.
Given that, you'll have to (also) store a list of all the districts as data in another document - one of which you know the name. For example, it's pretty common to include this info in an array field in the parent document of the districts collections - but other options are fine too.
